# Is there a reason not to include Nant files in your solution?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nant, projects-and-solutions

The project I'm currently working on uses Nant build scripts for the continuous integration server builds.  The build file is stored in a folder in the repository.

I find it annoying having to browse to it via windows explorer rather than it being available from the visual studio solution when I need to make changes.

I was wondering if there is any reason not to include it somewhere in the solution for ease of access?  If this isn't daft where would you store it in the solution?  Would you create a dummy non building project for holding these type of resources?

Thanks,
Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go right ahead and add it to your solution file.

You will either get, or have to create manually, a folder for it, but I think that when you add it you will get a folder called Solution Items.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did indeed create a folder called solution items and seems like a sensible enough place to keep them.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have seen, there is no real reason to not have them along with your project solution. In one project, since there were lots of build files, it made sense to create a separate solution for them.